# How to overlay color on texture in libgdx?

Tags: colors, libgdx, overlay

I'm using texture and textureAtlas in libgdx.
This textures loads images of white circle.

How can I overlay its color with another color?
Or maybe their is another approach for this?

```
private final static TextureAtlas textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("spritesheet.atlas"));
private final static TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion texture = textureAtlas.findRegion("Bubble.001");
```

**EDIT:**
As I said I have a white circle and I want to make it red (without the need for another image with a red circle)

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by overlay. Very vague word.

Comment: you can use `spriteBatch.setColor` to set a tint-color. Everything drawn with the `spritebatch` will then be tinted.

Comment: It doesn't work on white color...

Comment: If you are using `Sprites` instead of manually submitting texture regions to the sprite batch, then use `sprite.setColor` instead. If that doesn't work, you need to explain exactly what you're using for the texture. A PNG file with alpha channel?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lerp` method in Color class.

```
actor.setColor(Color.WHITE.cpy().lerp(tintingColor, .5f));
```

`lerp` changes your `Color` object, so use the `cpy` command before it to preserve the original color.  In this case I use WHITE as my original color, which preserves the color of your `Actor`'s texture.  `lerp` will overlay the tintingColor with a strength of 50% in this case.